# How do I force Firefox to always show the URL and navigation toolbar in popup windows?

Tags: firefox, popups

How do I prevent websites from disabling the URL bar navigation bar when they open popup windows using javascript. Here is an example of such a window: http://jsfiddle.net/nLmw8t5q/1/

Basically, I always want to see the URLbar/address bar and navigation controls. I am using Firefox.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into about:config, and change

```
dom.disable_window_open_feature.toolbar
```

from false to true.

That will do it!

Comment: I also had to set `dom.disable_window_open_feature.menubar` to `true` but it works!

Comment: Great!  Yep, if you also want the menu bar, that is the boolean setting to toggle to 'true' to prevent it from being hidden.  There are a whole bunch of settings under dom.disable that can be toggled to fine-tune customization to meet anyone's needs.

Answer (score 1):

The `dom.disable_window_open_feature.*` config options mentioned in the other answer appear to be unsupported in today's Firefox. However, the

```
browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction
```

option remains available. Setting its value to `0` (instead of the default `2`) in about:config causes all JavaScript popups to open as regular tabs, with full UI.

Details can be found in [this ancient MozillaZine KB article](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction).